# Regaining shell focus without exiting program in linux

Tags: linux, shell

(I know this isn't the place for this question, but this has been driving me insane. I've tried finding an answer online, but I don't know what words to use when I search.)

If I'm editing a program in a text editor, and then want to run it, the shell is still "in the text editor". I use ctrl + C to regain control of the shell and run the program, but this exits the text editor. There has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: Ctrl-Z is what you are looking for.  Or use `screen` to have multiple sessions in one shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use `CTRL+z` to put the text editor in the background. You can see a list of background processes by typing **jobs**. Bring the job back to the foreground with `fg %1` (assuming you have only one job).

For example:

```
$ jobs
[1]-  Stopped                 vim file1
[2]+  Stopped                 vim file2
$ fg %1 #Brings the "vim file1" back to the foreground
```